# AWS - How is EBS charged?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How is EBS charged? Is it Per stored data and bandwidth, per allocated storage and bandwidth, per stored data and IO operations or per allocated data IO operations?

Answer (score 3):

It's stated pretty clear inside the documentation

https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

Generally it's based on the disk type, provisioned size and provisioned IOPS ( where applicable ) multiplied by the amount of time until you delete the resource

Price also varies a bit region to region. To use or not the provisioned resource will have no effect on your billed amount

Also

> If you need help setting up AWS resources, ask those questions on Server Fault.